# Getting A Month's Worth of Data With KnexJS

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to get a month's worth of data using KnexJS, I only have the year and month in the form **20xx-mm**.

Here's my Knex query ..

```js
export function getMonthlyData(yearAndMonth, startingFromDay, roomId) {
  return db('events')
    .where('roomId', roomId)
    .whereBetween('start', [`${yearAndMonth}-${startingFromDay} 00:00:00+00`, `${yearAndMonth}-31 23:59:59+00`])
    .select();
}
```

The issue is, I'm starting at a specific date and going through to the 31'st day, some months have 30 days, some 28 and 29. How do I go about to creating a query that helps me achieve this?

I have tried using SQL's **MONTH** function along with Knex's **betweenRaw**, but unfortunately, I have only the year and month, and the **MONTH** function expects a datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it

```sql
export function getMonthlyData(yearAndMonth, startingFromDay, roomId) {
  const startDate = `${yearAndMonth}-${startingFromDay}`;
  return db('events')
    .where('roomId', roomId)
    .whereRaw(`start >= (TIMESTAMP '${startDate}')::DATE`)
    .whereRaw(`start < date_trunc('MONTH', TIMESTAMP '${startDate}' + interval '1 month')::DATE`)
    .select();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but, the code doesn't take into account my yearAndMonth parameter which represents a given date such as 2022-06. I tried it and it returned the results for the month of August only.

Comment: @saadsawash Updated code to use the provided start date parameters

Comment: That works, thank you @Kunal. I have on extra question and would be glad if you help me out. the Parameter startingFromDay contains an integer representing the starting date. For example when I provide the function with 2022-06 as a value for yearAndMonth it brings up everything in the month of June, and if I pass in 25 as the value for startingFromDay it again shows up everything in the month of June but starting from the 25'th instead of the 1'st of June. So the range for the data would be 25 - 30

Comment: @saadsawash The start date needed to be used as-is instead of using the month from the date. The current solution should work if you need it to start from a specific date

Comment: It doesn't work as expected @Kunal, I mean I give it the following date 2022-08-26 which should bring the data from the 26'th until the end of the month, but it also gets data from the 18'th 13'th of the month.

Comment: @saadsawash It should work. Explaining the query shows the correct filter as well: `Filter: ((start >= '2022-08-26'::date) AND (start < '2022-09-01'::date) AND (roomid = 1))`

Comment: I did a bit of experimenting on pgAdmin and I am sure your solution works, but in my code calling the function returns all queries with dates starting way below my selected one for some reason.

Comment: Follow Up: The column "start" is a TIMESTAMP with Timezone field, I don't think that'll work with comparison operators such as >= or < because the right side is of date type. I tried adding ::DATE to start but it didn't work as well.

Comment: @saadsawash Just replace `::DATE` with `::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and try